# Multi-level Group By clause is not allowed in a sub query

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

The Query is running fine in query design when i use TR.DocNo field in My report. an error msg pops up :

```
Multi-level Group By clause is not allowed in a sub query.
```

any ideas how can i fix it thanks

```
SELECT T.traID, 
           IIf(T.trawrhIDTo,"Purchase"," Sales ") AS FormSorP, 
           T.traDocNoID, 
           W.wrhName, 
           TS.trsPrice, 
           TS.trsVatRate,
           TS.trsAuxField, 
           WI.whiAdjustment, 
           W.wrhCountry,
           T.traDate AS TDATE, 
           TS.trsSubTotalGross,
           C.cstName AS CName, 
           TR.DocNo
         (SELECT tblTransactionsSC.traDocNoID AS DocNo
            FROM tblTransactionsSC
           WHERE (((tblTransactionsSC.traID)=[Forms]![frmReturns]![tratraID]))) AS TR
      FROM tblWarehouse AS W 
          INNER JOIN ((tblTransactionsSC AS T LEFT JOIN tblCustomer AS C ON T.tracstID = C.cstID)   
          INNER JOIN (tblTransactionsSubSC AS TS  
          LEFT JOIN tblWarehouseItem AS WI ON TS.trswhiID = WI.whiID) ON T.traID = TS.trstraID) ON W.wrhID = T.trawrhID
      WHERE (((T.traID)=[Forms]![frmReturns]![traID]));
```

Comment: You are missing comm like this TR.DocNo, check it

Comment: a comma? the query is compiled successfully, when i use it in my report to view TR.DocNo is not working

Answer (score 1):

You are missing comma check it

```
SELECT T.traID, 
           IIf(T.trawrhIDTo,"Purchase"," Sales ") AS FormSorP, 
           T.traDocNoID, 
           W.wrhName, 
           TS.trsPrice, 
           TS.trsVatRate,
           TS.trsAuxField, 
           WI.whiAdjustment, 
           W.wrhCountry,
           T.traDate AS TDATE, 
           TS.trsSubTotalGross,
           C.cstName AS CName, 
           TR.DocNo,
         (SELECT tblTransactionsSC.traDocNoID AS DocNo
            FROM tblTransactionsSC
           WHERE (((tblTransactionsSC.traID)=[Forms]![frmReturns]![tratraID]))) AS TR
      FROM tblWarehouse AS W 
          INNER JOIN ((tblTransactionsSC AS T LEFT JOIN tblCustomer AS C ON T.tracstID = C.cstID)   
          INNER JOIN (tblTransactionsSubSC AS TS  
          LEFT JOIN tblWarehouseItem AS WI ON TS.trswhiID = WI.whiID) ON T.traID = TS.trstraID) ON W.wrhID = T.trawrhID
      WHERE (((T.traID)=[Forms]![frmReturns]![traID]));
```

Comment: If i put the comma know TR.DocNo is not recognized and i have TR filed with the correct field value.  TR.DocNo not recognized stays empty

Comment: when i use that Query in my report. set a text have the value of TR.DocNo the same error occurs even with the comma